# Determine dates of DST switch (both forwards and backwards) for a timezone in Java?

Tags: java, datetime, date, dst

I realize that you can check if a `Date` is `inDaylightTime`, but how can I determine when (or if) that Date switches to and from DST? I can iterate over every day and check if it's inDaylightTime, but is there a cleaner solution/method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) - its [`DateTimeZone`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html) class has `nextTransition` and `previousTransition` methods.

Note that transitions can occur for reasons other than DST - a change in standard time, or perhaps a change in the name of the zone interval. But that's how you'd find out, anyway :)

(Joda Time is a much better date and time library to start with, to be honest.)

Comment: +1 and I would love to use a different library, but I should have mentioned I'm working with legacy code and have to use the Java Date and DateTime :-\

Comment: @GrailsDev: Even if you're not going to use Joda Time elsewhere, can you not introduce it *even for this bit*? (I can't see anything which will give you transitions in the Java standard classes, even for `SimpleTimeZone`.)

Comment: I suppose I can... was wondering more if it's possible in the default Java class.

Comment: @GrailsDev: Not that I can see. Joda Time makes it pretty easy to convert from a Java `Date` though. Maybe you can introduce it throughout the project by stealth ;)

Comment: Any way to do it without using Joda ? in Java version less than 8.

Comment: @DevilCode: Not that I'm aware of in an efficient way. See https://github.com/nodatime/tzvalidate/blob/master/java/org/nodatime/tzvalidate/Java7Dump.java#L67 for some code that works, but only by testing every day...

Answer (score 0):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:** Use [`ZoneRules#nextTransition`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html#nextTransition-java.time.Instant-) and [`ZoneRules#previousTransition`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html#previousTransition-java.time.Instant-).

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.zone.ZoneRules;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant now = Instant.now();
        ZoneRules zoneRules = ZoneId.of("Europe/London").getRules();

        System.out.println(zoneRules.nextTransition(now));

        System.out.println(zoneRules.previousTransition(now));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Transition[Overlap at 2021-10-31T02:00+01:00 to Z]
Transition[Gap at 2021-03-28T01:00Z to +01:00]
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/Ml29oj)

You can understand the output from the [following images](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/uk/london?year=2021):

[image]

From the image, you can see that on 28 Mar 2021, after 00:59, the time changed to 02:00 i.e. **there was no 01:00 that night**. Is there a way to know the local time and the zone offset just before the transition happened? Check [`ZoneOffsetTransition`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/zone/ZoneOffsetTransition.html#getDateTimeBefore--) or the following demo for the answer.

### What were the local time and the zone offset before the transition?

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.zone.ZoneOffsetTransition;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("Europe/London");
        ZoneOffsetTransition nextTransition = zoneId.getRules().previousTransition(Instant.now());
        System.out.println("Local date-time before the transition: " + nextTransition.getDateTimeBefore());
        System.out.println("Zone offset before the transition: " + nextTransition.getOffsetBefore());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Local date-time before the transition: 2021-03-28T01:00
Zone offset before the transition: Z
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/ZHouf1)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>